# How should apache/nginx and django play nicely together in respect of 404 errors?

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, http-status-code-404

Here is a simplified version of our setup:

- Nginx reverse proxy front end serving static files
- Apache + mod_wsgi serving a django app in /store and wordpress for all other URLs

404 errors outside /store work fine (via an apache 404 handler).

However, 404 errors within /store hit the django 404.html. I'd really like not to repeat myself within that file (DRY!) and so would love to have 404 errors handled by apache (or nginx, I'm not fussy) across the site.

I am completely new to nginx, relatively new to django and have a bit of experience hacking wordpress and apache around over the years.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could always symlink your 404 page as `{django}/templates/404.html`

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out what I think is the "correct" way of doing this which is to set:
 WSGIErrorOverride On

In my Apache vhost. This seems to achieve the desired goal of Apache handle the 404 errors.

Comment: Noting that WSGIErrorOverride directive only works for mod_wsgi daemon mode.